# Using different enable.auto.commit value for different KafkaConsumer with same group id

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What happens if there are two applications app1 and app2, each has its own consumer groups but with same consumer group id G1. app1 consumer group has enable.auto.commit set to *TRUE* and app2 has enable.auto.commit set to *FALSE*. And app2 will never commit any offset, because its for some admin tasks that should not affect app1.

With above setup can app2 consumer do its tasks, without affecting app1? app2 tasks are performed at regular interval, like logging some messages, calculating count of messages unread messages by fetching all messages from the current committed offset (the offset committed by app1) to the end?

Update: app1 consumer is initialized with *subscribe()* method, but the app2 consumer is initialized with *assign()* so that app1 consumers are not rebalanced when app2 consumers are joining the consumer group G1 or detaching from G1.

Comment: IMO, the manually assigned consumer would not affect the group although they shared a same group id.

Comment: ok, but if manually assigned consumer (C) will affect the consumers in group (G1) if C commits some offset right?

Comment: As far as I know, `C` should not be allowed to commit offsets since the coordinator regards it as an unknown member.